# AWS Reserved Instance c3.large will Renew Automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I have little query related to reserved c3.large going to 1 year and it was reserved for 1 year does it will renew automatically or i need to do it manually.

If yes please advise how i can do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually 'renew' a reserved instance - you buy another one. Remember a reserved instance is just a billing construct and has nothing to do with any particular instance that may or may not be running.

So when the term of the reserved instance runs out, any instances you have simply start getting billed at the on-demand rate, unless and until you purchase another reserved instance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it manually. From: [Reserved Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts-on-demand-reserved-instances.html)

> **Reserved instances do not renew automatically**; you can continue using the EC2 instance without interruption, but you will be charged
>   On-Demand rates.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are correct, but for my use case the easiest thing was to let the instance expire and then "Purchase More Like These". See details [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reserved-instances-expire/).